# STM32 seems to ignore GPIO mode and triggers the interrupt on both edges, instead of one

Tags: stm32, interrupt, gpio

Here's my configuration:

```c
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = 8;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOJ, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

When I put the signal on the input pin (square, 2Hz, 3.3Vp-p) I get an interrupt every 250ms, so - on every RISING and falling edge of the signal. I changed the test signal duty cycle to test if it's really what is happening and it confirmed it. I get the interrupt on both edges.

I even debugged the HAL driver to test if it does what I think it does. And yes, it seems to configure the EXTI correctly, only for the falling edge for my pin.

What may be the cause of such behavior? My device is STM32H747I-DISCO discovery board with TouchGFX software used for presentation. The software works correctly, I tested it on measuring the time between other timer interrupts.

I monitor the test signal on the oscilloscope to ensure the input signal on my pin is correct. I tried to use another pin on the same port, but I observe identical behavior. I get interrupts on both rising and falling edges of the signal, despite the pin is configured to trigger the interrupt only on the falling edge.

I also tested the case with the rising edge only. Also in this case I get the interrupt on both edges.

Comment: Please, post the entire pieces of code that set up the line as interrupt. All calls to all HAL functions related, as well as corresponding NVIC setup lines. Just in case. Since the problem has to be somewhere there. Also, if you could post EXTI special function registers while you're getting your both edge interrupts, it would help a lot.

Comment: As I figured out later - it was a hardware error, a capacitor in the circuit produced a voltage spike narrow enough my scope didn't catch it with selected time base. After removing the capacitor the EXTI input worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be a hardware error, a voltage spike I overlooked. The STM32 EXTI input worked correctly all the time. There was indeed a spurious falling edge.

[image: Switching]

Simulated problem illustration, the 10n capacitor causes voltage spikes and spurious edge detection. In the real circuit, when a digital oscilloscope was used and the time base was too long to capture the spike - the signal looked like a proper square wave. After shortening the time base I noticed the spike. As it is shown on the illustration, this behavior can be easily simulated in a circuit simulator:

[SIMULATION LINK](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWK0wBYGoJybWgbGABwBMkaICkFIqAzBQKYC0YYAUKpAOwiFWmEQAoZEHsA5uC54hnKTNqkoUNgCd5IsdN5V%20pSGwBKGvhtSDdNKrWj1LMBGwBmQrsU0hF-UZ-dhoSDCQxGoewsK0kKjKYPBwbJIRUR5eygaSpsRypqm6RuAywkyYhT784PDg0HhI-jVpAaGZPmClFp6RbLR4guE%20xISCeNF53YLNgua%20aWwA7hp9vWUckPS0CO4sMgiY7ghg7lSxAPpgx5DHAB6ErAfHCOcoxyzHxKfQxA8XJ7SPwV9sADGrnc4TcnmSR2YFlgJW4kAQeCRtG6tFQYDssDICRBEOixHBuRU8wJoP65IsONSxCyvmsSjynHoLG0WSoUw27VYp3OVxurDeXyeLzeMFFpzOvyCn3ObCAA)

Removing the capacitor from the circuit solved the problem.

To avoid getting noise and other spurious signals on the input shielded wires can be used. The real world circuit was tested and it works properly without the capacitor.

The opto-coupler is just a simplified model of the optical sensor used in the real machine.

Comment: it would have been nice if you sketched a rough schematic of what exactly the wrong connection was

Comment: @Ilya Here. Take a look. I tried to explain what has happened.